# html input pattern валидное значение по умолчанию

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, input

Есть ли какое-нибудь валидное значение по умолчанию у pattern ? Смоделируем ситуацию в которой у нас в ЛЮБОМ СЛУЧАЕ ЕСТЬ этот атрибут у input, но поле должно принимать любое значение кроме пустого.
Со "*" работает, но валидатор ругается

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="type here.." required pattern="*">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях, `*` это квантификатор "0 и более раз".
Квантификаторы не могут использоваться сами по себе, без токена.

Более правильные выражения:

- `.*` - любое количество любых символов
- `.+` - как минимум один любой символ
- `\S+` - как минимум один непробельный символ

Второй вариант подходит к задаче вопроса (любое значение кроме пустого), следовательно

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="type here.." required pattern=".+">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

---

*<sup>// Пояснение ниже - для тех, у кого нет условия «атрибут pattern есть у input'ов в любом случае».</sup>*
А вообще, достаточно указать только атрибут `required` (не указывая атрибут `pattern`): будет тот же самый эффект, что и у шаблона `.+`:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="type here.." required>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```